# Rails CSS Compiling

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I recently ran bundle install for a rails app, which placed a ruby folder in my vendor folder that contains bin, cache, doc, gem, etc.

Since doing that, it appears that my CSS styling is running into a conflict.  I am using bootstrap as well as an overrides file, but where my styling is messed up, I am noticing :before and :after in odd places when inspecting element.

Certain elements seem to have lost their styling, but others look ok.  I am guessing that my styling is being overridden somewhere, but I don't understand how it is happening.

Can anyone please help me understand how to fix and avoid this in the future?  It seems like my vendor folder may be overriding the styling I implemented.

My application.css.scss

```
/*
* This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
* listed below.
*
* Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
* or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
*
* You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
* compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
*
*= require_self
*= require font-awesome
*= require bootstrap_and_overrides
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Move require_self last line of the manifest file.

Comment: I tried this and the same results - losing some styling.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

so, basically CSS overrides happen like that

1) The last one wins
2) More specific CSS selector wins (no matter where it's defined)

So, if you make patches to bootstrap, make sure you put them *after* you included bootstrap itself, and secondly try to use more specific CSS selectors, say use your app specific css class names and things like that.